# Where is MSPSCAN.EXE in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, scanner

Is there a new version `MSPSCAN.EXE` in `Windows 7`?
Or i can't find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MSPSCAN.exe` is part of Microsoft Office Document Imaging. For it to be present, you must have a version of Office installed with Microsoft Office Document Imaging selected during the install process.

Note that Office 2010 (Office14) does NOT have the Document Imaging functionality.

If you have Office installed, you should be able to find `MSPSCAN.exe` in the folder `%ProgramFiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSPaper\` (32-bit) or `%CommonProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Shared\MODI\1X.0\` (64-bit), where 1X.0 is your Office version (10.0, 11.0, 12.0)

C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSPaper